# How To Append Data From Ajax To Dual List Box

Tags: ajax, laravel, drop-down-menu

I'm working with Dual List Box from https://github.com/maykinmedia/dual-listbox

my backend with laravel, and i sure thats working, because i try with simple select box and working, but no with Dual List box,

here my code HTML.

```
 <select class="select1" id="select1" multiple>

  </select>
```

Js for Dual List box

```
let dlb2 = new DualListbox('.select1', {
    availableTitle:'Available Users',
    selectedTitle: 'Selected Users',
    addButtonText: '>',
    removeButtonText: '<',
    addAllButtonText: '>>',
    removeAllButtonText: '<<',
    searchPlaceholder: 'search user'
});
dlb2.addEventListener('added', function(event){
    console.log(event);
});
dlb2.addEventListener('removed', function(event){
    console.log(event);
});
```

Ajax, the **#source_user** that from another selectbox.

```
 $('#source_user').change(function(){
            var source = $(this).val();

            if(source){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url:"{{ url('get/user') }},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache:false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(result){
                       if(result){
                        // console.log(result);

                        $("#select1").empty();
                        $.each(result,function(key,value){
                            dlb2.redraw();
                            $("#select1").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');

                        });
                      }else{
                        console.log(result);
                     }
                  }
                });
            }
```

the output of result :

left is ID and Right is Name of users

```
{0e39aa7f-c0c5-4150-8699-e0d606aecf74: "Arif", 126318af-d7eb-42c0-b8ea-745004a99166: "1q23123", 19cb6c0f-bcd8-4f73-9c4e-54ed830028cc: "nnnn", 53b8c20e-8dd1-4ab0-9743-ad41bbbdc658: "awaeawe", 5b86bd19-aa74-4932-9f9a-a12c2a7949dd: "khkkh", …}
0e39aa7f-c0c5-4150-8699-e0d606aecf74: "Arif"
5b86bd19-aa74-4932-9f9a-a12c2a7949dd: "khkkh"
5dd6506b-827b-4063-ab52-10581c1828eb: "gagag"
19cb6c0f-bcd8-4f73-9c4e-54ed830028cc: "nnnn"
53b8c20e-8dd1-4ab0-9743-ad41bbbdc658: "awaeawe"
86c26b5d-0905-4842-9c60-f5177b162c57: "ggwp"
126318af-d7eb-42c0-b8ea-745004a99166: "1q23123"
bbcd38e5-fd14-48fd-b990-0f5f6df4dacb: "Bambangs"
```

Comment: can you add `result` op in your question as well ?

Comment: does your browser console shows any error ? check if your json is valid or not ?

Comment: @Swati there is no error, i've try with simple dropdown,  user data appears.
so i assume my json is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Due to confuse to appending data, 
i move to easy one https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox .

and it's work like a charm :)

Comment: does this `https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox` support ajax? meaning we can filter using ajax?

Comment: yes, you can. @thanzeel

Comment: how ? can u provide an example